# Slow aggregate - mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection which contains some results of website crawler. 
The document schema looks more or less like this:

```
{
  mainID: "number",
  // sometimes very big, up to 10,000 right now
  links: [
    {
        foo: 'bar',
    },
    //... more documents
  ]
}
```

I need to query this collection to get some statistics of a user account. Statistics are calculated for each of a last inserted document per mainID.

All the documents are reports for mainID (inserted frequently).

I currently use this query to get all data at once (before a had query for each mainID, the timing was similar if not exactly the same):

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate([
{
            $match: {
              mainID: {
                $in: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
              },
            }
          },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: "$mainID",
              links: {
                $first: "$links"
              },
              // some more fields here
            }
          }
])
```

The query takes ~3 to 5 seconds to get the data. I then do some additional statistics calculations on links array like doing some counts on fields depending on the value. This takes some milliseconds. mainID is also indexed, which should speed up first $match.

I'm quite new in mongo, and not sure how to proceed with this. Since the feature is still quite experimental, I'm also open to change the schema. No migration will be needed, I can still flush all data and start over.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a more specific example, e.g. 1) a document example that contains the necessary fields, and 2) an aggregation example that is actually aligned with the document example? It's unclear what is `$contentTestId`, why do you need `$first`, etc.

Comment: oh, I changed key names but obviously not all. Edited the question.

I need $first to get the last inserted document fields for every mainID i query.

I already noticed that when I $group without .links it's blazing fast. .links is a a big array, therefore I suspect it's just a fetching issue.

Comment: If without `links` it's fast, it's also possible that it's an index issue. What indexes do you have on the collection? Could you post the query `explain()` result? More info here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/ and here's how you can explain an aggregation query: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/ (see the `options` section)

Comment: I rewrite the whole query, to first do the group to get _id (mongo ids) for the documents I need ($group->$first). Then on another query, just .find by those _id(s). $group stage is blazing fast, .find() (which fetches links) is slow again. 

I have index only for _id and mainID. Is there any reason I should have links for fields I fetch? Or maybe it's slow because of the server performance and size of links (at least on fetched document has a length of 10,000).

Comment: Thank you @KevinAdistambha for pointing me in the right direction. Caching statistics separately is the answer for my pain. Big array in .links field was the reason.

Comment: Glad to know you solved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some benchmarking and trying different ways of getting the same result I finally found out that the problem was not how I get the data, but what I get.

Some documents' .link field had 10K elements in an array. It was enough to have one of those in aggregation to make the whole query slow.

I strongly believe this is because of the read performance of my mongo instance.

I fixed it by changing the way I store this data. Now I compute the statistics I really need from .links array before the document is inserted into a database.

This way I can pick only few fields when I show lists of data and fetch all the data when it's really needed (single document view).